# Images attached from tinyMce with different paths in admin panel and front side

Tags: javascript, php, image, tinymce

In admin panel where image is related to path `../gallery/image-09_05_16_02_27_37-references_4.jpg` it looks ok:

[image]

But in the front site there is wrong path to image:

[image]

should be: `gallery/image-09_05_16_02_27_37-references_4.jpg`.

**What should I do to display proper path in both: admin and front site?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `relative_urls: false` and  `convert_urls: false` and give full absolute url of image in editor..

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        tinyMCE.init({
            elements : "email-template-template",
            width : "100%",
            relative_urls : false,
            convert_urls: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: It was really helpul. Thanks;)

Comment: glad to help you @BartłomiejSemańczyk ;) now you can  accept my answer as well :)